# typescript custom type is not assignable to custom type

Tags: typescript

Let me give you an example to make the question simple.

```
type TA = 1 | 2;
type TB = 3 | 4;
type TC = TA | TB;

const a: TA[] = [1, 2];
const b: TC[] = [1, 2, 3, 4];

b.forEach((e) => {
  a.includes(e);
            ^^^
});
```

Argument of type `TC` is not assignable to parameter of type `TA`.
Type `3` is not assignable to type `TA`.

I'm knowing the reason it didn't work but I can't find out any solutions to check `a` has an element of `e`.

Comment: This is a typical TS overkill error. Just `//@ts-ignore` it.

Comment: @hackape Don't `//@ts-ignore` that is a blunt tool, you have no clue what you are ignoring as the code changes. You just ignore all errors on the next line. Use a type assetion `a.includes(e as TA);`

Comment: TS is right about complaining. You need to type check for that.

Comment: I personally think the `Array.prototype.test_ish()` methods family need their declarations fixed. I should be allowed to put anything to be tested.

Comment: @hackape I don't think passing a number to an array of objects is necessarily what I want, since that probably is an error. I'd rather deal with the few casses where I want this with a type assertion.

Comment: @hackape that is against the static type checking.

Answer (score 3):

`include` takes an element of the same type as the array element. In this case that type is `TA`. So `TC` (while a union of `TA` and `TB`) might not be of the same type.

Now `include` is a special case, while in the case of an array of numbers we probably don't want to allow strings to be passed into include, in the case of unions of literal types we would actually want to be able to pass in an argument that may be of one of the literal types in the array, since testing for presence is actually what `include` does. Unfortunately TS does not have a way to easily model 'if the array element is a literal type allow the base type to be passed in'

The simplest, and most targeted solution here is a type assertion:

```
type TA = 1 | 2;
type TB = 3 | 4;
type TC = TA | TB;

const a: TA[] = [1, 2];
const b: TC[] = [1, 2, 3, 4];

b.forEach((e) => {
  a.includes(e as TA);
});
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKgglAvFAjFAPlATAbgFCiSwBCSUAzBlACz6HQwDCZ8VMx+eAxgPYB2AZ2BQAhgC5YcANoBdMlJQAabDPy9BwgEYSms+UuzLyy6qrx5NAOgBmPAE4BREVwAWACjcQAlEgB8UAG88KFFLAEs+LgAbAFcAEwgBT1EBSS98EMyszLwAX3SgA)

Comment: That's what I thought at first but I felt that's quite tricky and still not readable. I mean, `e as TA` seems like e is type TA. However, your recommendation works well. Cool

Comment: @sunsets You are lying a bit to the compiler. But in this case there will be no runtime errors caused by this.